# telnetlib.telnet in connection to KVM console

Tags: console, connection, telnet, kvm

I tried to connect to console , but I'm stuck without response from connection,
can somebody help me?
I'm executing this code on ubuntu,
Thanks

```
import logging
import telnetlib
import time
from sys import stdin, stdout


# KVM console auth
server_ip = "x.x.x.x"
server_port = 5025
server_username = "apc"
server_password = "Apc"
try:
    # Connect to console
    telnet_con = telnetlib.Telnet(host = "x.x.x.x", port = 5025)
    response_all1 = telnet_con.read_all().decode("ascii")
    print(response_all1)
    # output = telnet_con.read_all().decode("ascii")
    # print(output)
    command1 = 'olOn 6'
    # Login to KVM
    telnet_con.read_until(b"User Name : ")
    telnet_con.write(server_username.encode("ascii") + b"\n")
    telnet_con.read_until(b"Password  : ")
    telnet_con.write(server_password.encode("ascii") + b"\n")
    # time.sleep(3)
    response_all = telnet_con.read_all().decode("ascii")
    print(response_all)
    response = telnet_con.read_until(b"apc>")

except Exception as e:
    print("An error occured: ", e)
telnet_con.close()
```

========================================

I'm expecting to run the commands after that I'll receive the prompt "apc>"